# Difference between $A\to B\to C$ and $A\to(B\to C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relation-algebra

As the title says, what is the difference between $A\to B\to C$ and $A\to(B\to C)$? I have tried to reduce these expressions into $A\to B === (A\text{ OR } \text{NOT} B)$ form but didn't get anywhere. Any references will be much appreciated.

---

After posting here, I just stumbled on Wolfram's: (Wolfram Alpha considers A→B→C to be equal to (A→B)→C, which is wrong as explained in @Yuri's answer). However, the technique is neat.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+implies+b+implies+c%29+vs+%28a+implies+%28b+implies+c%29%29

Comment: What does the left mean? Informally I would read it as $(A \rightarrow B) \wedge (B\rightarrow C)$ but you should check your definitions/conventions...

Comment: Also, assuming $\rightarrow$ is implication, the correct reduction is $(A\rightarrow B) \equiv (B \vee \neg A)$, *not* $(A \vee B)$.

Comment: @user7530 thanks, that was a formatting mistake. ALSO, I was putting NOT on B instead of A. I didn't correct the second so that your comment remains relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard convention is that the implication operation is right-associative. That is, $A\to B \to C$ means $A\to (B\to C)$. Now $(A\to B) \to C$ is **not** equivalent to $A\to (B\to C)$. Consider what happens when $A = B= C =false$.

Comment: can you provide some reference for → associativity? As you put it, this seems that A→B→C and A→(B→C) are equal.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781447141280-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1334404-p174507422 : “Although the implication operator is assumed to be right associative, so that $p \to q \to r$ unambiguously means $p \to (q \to r)$, we will write the formula with parentheses to avoid confusion with $(p\to q)\to r$.”

Comment: Or http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g52ifr/html/Prop.html : “Implication is right associative, i.e. we read P -> Q -> R as P -> (Q -> R).”